# fast-forwards error after rebasing Git

Tags: git, push, rebase

I use my git repository in two different computers.
 I had to run some tests on the Desktop so I created branch X, then I did some work on the master branch and had to rebase X and squash some commits to create patches then I force-pushed the changes to the remote repo.

Afterwards I cloned the repo to my laptop and did some changes but now when I try to push it complaints about fast-forwards and that I have to make a git-pull(which I dont want to do since I have rebased and squashed/edited commits again)
All I want is to have a clone of the repo as I on my laptop on the origin repository

So the question is: Is force-push my only option?

Comment: That's what you get for rewriting history. I don't understand why people like to `git-rebase` so much, it seems like a terrible idea to me.

Comment: hmm if you are tracking a collaborative project and the master branch gets updated often or other people's branches get updated often then you need to rebase your work on top of their latest one to be sure that your stuff is working

Comment: **Or** you can merge master with your branch to make sure that your stuff is working. In fact, the end result is the same, it's just the history that gets changed with `git-rebase` and it's possibly more difficult to resolve conflicts, not to mention the kind of trouble you have currently ran into. You should know by now that you should never push a rebased branch to any remote (because that messes up everyone's histories)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want your branch on the remote machine to be exactly like on your laptop and discard whatever differences there are: `git push -f` does exactly that. It pushes your local branch's state to the remote repo and forcibly sets the remote branch to the tip of what you just pushed. Any commits the remote branch contained that aren't referenced in your local branch or elsewhere will be unreachable.